# Importing JFoenix in JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 crashes the app

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

When I load the `jfoenix-8.0.7.jar` through "Import JAR/FXML file", the program refuses to load and becomes unresponsive. I have tried deselecting all and just importing one, but the result was the same: unresponsive.

How can I import JFoenix and use the components in Scene Builder?

Comment: Scene Builder 2.0 is long outdated; try a [more recent version](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) (from Gluon). You may have to use Scene Builder 8.x.x when using JFoenix 8.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

Scene Builder 2.0 is probably not compatible with java 1.8. Deinstall it and [Install Scene Builder 8.5.0](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) Also there is JFoenix 8.0.8 avaliable, you could update it, too. If you're using Scene Builder trough Eclipse, you should start Eclipse and Scene Builder as Administrator. Else Scene Builder can crash very fast. (Just set it in both .exe)